# getting correct value from field

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

I am having issue on elasticsearch.
I can finally post to elasticsearch but the data is being written with a 'S' value instead of the actual value.

When I check my cloudwatch logs I see this.

```
{
    "Records":[
    {
        "eventID":"d5d4955d706dd71348760a482f33735f",
        "eventName":"INSERT",
        "eventVersion":"1.1",
        "eventSource":"aws:dynamodb",
        "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
        "dynamodb":{
            "ApproximateCreationDateTime":1613816980.0,
            "Keys":{
                "uuid":{
                    "S":"c140a68de65301465cd1cd3d97cc4107"
                }
            },
            "NewImage":{
                "SmsStatus":{
                    "S":"received"
                },
                "streetname":{
                    "S":"King tut"
                },
                "timestampMessage":{
                    "S":"Sat Feb 20 2021 10:29:39 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"
                }
            }
        }
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the code I am using.

```
import os
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

es_host = os.environ['ES_HOST']
es_index = "metadata"
es_type = "episodes"
url = es_host + '/' + es_index + '/' + es_type + '/'

region = 'us-east-1'
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    for record in event['Records']:
        id = str(record['dynamodb']['Keys']['uuid']['S'])
        if record['eventName'] == 'REMOVE':
            res = requests.delete(url + id, auth=awsauth)
        else:
            document = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']
            res = requests.put(url + id, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

Im sure this is something small to fix but im not certain how to please if someone could assist. thanks

Comment: What's is the actual value and what is the `S`? Can you point that out please?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear.
In the cloudwatch logs above you will see this entry.
'Keys': {'uuid': {'S': 'c140a68de65301465cd1cd3d97cc4107'}}, 'NewImage': {'SmsStatus': {'S': 'received'}, 'streetname': {'S': 'King tut'}
For this entry for the dynamodb entry with uuid c140a68de65301465cd1cd3d97cc4107 it added the 'S' .  I think the 'S' that is being written to elasticsearch is as result of this part of the query but fails without it. 
id = str(record['dynamodb']['Keys']['uuid']['S'])
The entries end up with only the titles like "From", "ProfileName",etc...and value of S in es document

Comment: The 'S' value is the event tag from dynamodb according to the video I saw it in . @ChetanRanpariya. Does that clarify it please?

Comment: You might want to do `id = record.dynamodb.Keys.uuid.S`

Comment: I gave this a try

for record in event['Records']:
        id = record.dynamodb.Keys.uuid.S
        if record['eventName'] == 'REMOVE':

but it gave the error "[ERROR] AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dynamodb'" 

Am I using correctly please? @ChetanRanpariya?

Comment: Yes.. I  think my suggestion won't work. I think you should try to do `print(id)` and `print(url + id)` and `print(document)` in your original code to see what actual value you are getting. I tried to run your code and I am getting the value of `S` (c140a68de65301465cd1cd3d97cc4107) when I did `print(id)`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya we getting the same value. I did not articulate myself well enough. the results above is correct with the value S (c140a68de65301465cd1cd3d97cc4107)  but what I wanted to see was uuid (c140a68de65301465cd1cd3d97cc4107) and not its subcategory os S . The data is however present which is what I needed. I just need to get into the kibana login to view it . thank you